# Archive only the latest .png files in a katalon jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, katalon-studio

I need to archive any .png screenshots of the latest katalon test run in Jenkins as a post-build step of the same test run.

Using the "archive the artifacts" post-build action in Jenkins, I currently have the file path set to `Reports/**/[test run name]/**/*.png` where Reports is in the workspace directory. However this will just pull every .png file from the current and all previous test runs stored there, of which are kept stored in the workspace for a week before being cleaned out.

I've tried using the "Exclude" field but haven't been able to figure out a way to exclude older files with only being able to use a file path with wildcards.

Is there a way in Jenkins, using archive the artifacts or something else, to archive just the .png files generated by the same job without deleting all previously generated .png files?

Answer (score 0):

From our experience, it's better to keep the artifacts archived with the job and not rely on files residing in the workspace together with a separate job to clean them. You can tell Jenkins to discard old builds (and artifacts) with something like this:

```
pipeline {
  options {
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(daysToKeepStr: '7', artifactDaysToKeepStr: '7'))
  }
}
```

And any jobs (and their artifacts) will be cleaned after 7 days.

If you go with that path, you can safely remove any `png` files after archiving them as artifacts, and you won't need to find out which are new and which are old.

Alternatively, you can order your `png`-producing step to name the files starting with the job number (available as `env.BUILD_NUMBER`) and only archive the files starting with this number.

Finally, you can run `find` command with `-name '*png'` and  `-mtime` predicate to produce the list of recently modified `png` files, and use that as an input to the archive step.